# If factor isn't found in P-1 algorithm, should upper bound be increased linearly (i.e. +1)

Tags: algorithms, discrete-mathematics, factoring

I have seen some implementations of [Pollard's P-1 algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_p_%E2%88%92_1_algorithm) where the upper bound is only increased by 1 if no factor is found. Such an implementation is [described here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pollard-p-1-algorithm/). Is it sort of missing the point in terms of efficiency to only increase by 1, or is is it sill better than trial division for finding a factor? Is what they're implementing in the link really the P-1 algorithm? I've seen [other sources](https://frenchfries.net/paul/factoring/theory/pollard.p-1.html) make it sound that a certain amount of intuition is needed when choosing parameters and you shouldn't just increase by 1 each time. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: There isn't a single version of the $p-1$ algorithm. For example, the Wikipedia version requires a smoothness bound in advance, which it doesn't update at all.

Comment: I suggest trying out several implementations, and checking which one performs best.

Comment: That said, note that the geeksforgeeks implementation computes $a^{i!}$ in the $(i-1)$'th step. So the upper bound doesn't increase by 1 each time, as your post claims.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus sorry, I don't get your last comment. `Until a factor is returned do...i <- i+1`

Comment: If by "upper bound" you mean upper bound on the largest prime factor, then it does increase by 1.

Comment: There is a tradeoff here – GCD is costly, so perhaps you should increase $i$ by a bit more. Or perhaps not. The easiest way to tell is to test it.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science SE. This looks a math question.